# How to use web farm framework and octopus deployment

Tags: teamcity, nuget-package, web-farm-framework, octopus-deploy

I have done a setup for automation deployment using team-city and octopus. it is successfully deploying to required servers but I need to load balance as well. Any idea how can I combine them together. Or any other best option for performing load balancing with octopus.

Comment: Hi sam -- just checking in. How are you doing with this?

Comment: I want to do it with NLB. Now trying to write a script for it but stuck at credentials step. Any idea. please check my query here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021459/getting-stop-nlbclusternode-a-parameter-cannot-be-found-that-matches-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octopus can tie into your load balancing solution, but it will not perform load balancing.

Most enterprise applications use a hardware network load balancing appliance.  For example F5's Big-IP product line.  You can also create a software solution like John Hoerr suggested.

Once you have a solution in place you can then script Octopus to automate configuring your load balancer in a way that meets you business needs.

Answer (score 1):

We use the [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module) extension for IIS to provide load balancing for our WFF-based farm.  ARR requires an additional 'front-end' IIS server which acts as a reverse proxy for your 'back-end' application servers.  It works a treat, and we've been really happy with it.